# serial Version of Karel

Tags: stanford-nlp, karel

I recently started to learn about Programming through iTunes U, in CS106A at Stanford through the videos. And I am now working with Karel or so to write.

I followed the instructions about downloading everything to the letter but when I start to write a set of methods, the system tells me that it can't find the version that I am using and in the Assignment1 package, when I am looking through Eclipse, every sub-portion of Assignment1 has a warning triangle with it.

```
public class *CollectNewspaperKarel* extends SuperKarel {

public void run() {
```

*collectnewspaperKarel* is underlined in yellow.

And every program, is underlined in yellow. When I try to change by generating versions of the software it still can't run it. What should I do, because I can't even try any combination that I create? Karel is still standing still in all the given worlds.

Answer (score 0):

as you need to do this task only once, left button on triangle and try other solutions - suppress warning or add default serial version ID, worked for me.